# Titanium - CoreData error wrapping ADTECHMobileSDK in an iOS native module

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, module, titanium

We’re working to build a native **iOS titanium module** to wrap the **ADTECHMobileSDK** library, a library we use for ads.
We successfully manage to port the banner views but we’re having troubles with interstitials:

The app crashes when the method -load is called on the interstitial with the following message

> +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name ‘Asset’

It seems to be a CoreData problem, but I have not access to the native code.

There are 3 things you have to configure on an interstitial: 
a configuration
a delegate
and a view controller

The library handles the wrong values for these 3 parameters with 3 particular exceptions, so I think we are setting all the 3 in the right way.
We also checked we imported correctly the library resource bundle that you’re asked to import in the project
 (and that contains the CoreData models), the library throws a particular exception when it’s missing too so it should have been done correctly.

I’m not a CoreData expert so I would like to know what could cause that exception and what should I check, or if there are any known issues building a module with a third party library that uses CoreData.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be a cuncurrency issue.

Debugging from Xcode with a symbolic breakpoint on the [NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] 
i found out it was called on different threads. 
I resolved forcing the load call on the main thread using the titanium macro

ENSURE_UI_THREAD(load, args);